# The token was expected to have 3 parts, but got 4

Tags: angular, spring

Tested with postman and everything works fine, so its frontend issue. My key for the token is the same as the one i put in angular as well.

Also once i log in i receive an error with a GET request to a list of users when this works flawlessly in postman. But i don't know how relevant that is to this because we already know its the token.

[image]

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';
import { NotificationService } from 'src/app/services/notification.service';
import { User } from 'src/app/model/user';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NotificationType } from 'src/app/enum/notification-type.enum';
// once the login.component.html is loaded, it will call this file
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
public showLoading: boolean; 

private subscription: Subscription[]=[]; 

  constructor(private router: Router, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ,private notificationService: NotificationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn())
    {
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/user/management");
    }
    else
    {
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
    }

  }
  public onLogin(user: User): void
  {
    this.showLoading = true; 
    console.log(user);
    this.subscription.push(
      this.authenticationService.login(user).subscribe(
      (response: HttpResponse<User>) =>
      {
        const token = response.headers.get('Jwt-Token');
        this.authenticationService.saveToken(token);
        this.authenticationService.addUserToLocalCache(response.body);
       
        this.router.navigateByUrl("user/management");
        this.showLoading = false; // since were not at login page anymore
      }, 
      (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) =>
      {
        console.log(errorResponse);
        this.sendErrorNotification(NotificationType.ERROR,errorResponse.error.message);
        this.showLoading = false;
      }
    ));
  }
  private sendErrorNotification(notificationType: NotificationType, message: string): void {
    if(message) 
    {
      this.notificationService.showNotification(notificationType,message); 
    }
    else{
      this.notificationService.showNotification(notificationType,"An error occurred, please try again"); 

    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void{
    this.subscription.forEach(sub=>sub.unsubscribe); 
}

}
```

authentication.service.ts:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  public host = environment.apiurl;
  private token: string;
  private LoggedInUsername: string;
  private jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  
  public login(user: User): Observable<HttpResponse<User> | HttpErrorResponse>
  {                                                                                                                                  
    return this.http.post<User> (`${this.host}/user/login`,user,{observe: `response`});

                                                                         
  }
  public register(user: User): Observable<User | HttpErrorResponse>
  {                                                                                                                                
    return this.http.post<User | HttpErrorResponse>
    (`${this.host}/user/register`,user);
  }

  public logOut(): void
  {                                                                                                                                   
    this.token = null;
    this.LoggedInUsername = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('users');
  }
  public saveToken(token: string): void
  {                                                                                                                                  
    this.token = token;
    localStorage.setItem('token',token); // token: "spdinvps", so like key = 'token' value = token variable
   
  }
  public addUserToLocalCache(user: User): void
  {                                                                                                                                 
    localStorage.setItem('token',JSON.stringify(user)); 
  }
  public getUserFromLocalCache(): User
  {     
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));                                                                                                                  
  }
  public loadToken(): void 
  {     
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
  public getToken(): string 
  {     
    return this.token;
  }
  // check to see if user is logged in or not
  public isLoggedIn(): boolean 
  {     this.loadToken(); // load token
    // if token isnt null or empty ill login, otherwise logout and return false
    if(this.token != null && this.token !=='')
    {
      // now we need to get make sure subject isnt null or empty
      if(this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token).sub != null || '')
        if(!this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token))
        {
        this.LoggedInUsername = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token).sub; 
        } 
    }
    else 
    {
    this.logOut();
    return false;
    } 
  }
}
```

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiurl: 'http://localhost:8480' // could put this in userservice put better to put it globally here
};
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './interceptor/auth.interceptor';
import { NotificationModule } from './notification.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NotificationModule,
   
  ],
  providers: [ 
   {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass: AuthInterceptor,multi:true}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

auth.interceptor.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor( private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, httpHandler: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
    if(httpRequest.url.includes(`${this.authenticationService.host}/user/login`)) 
    {
        return httpHandler.handle(httpRequest); 
    }
 
    if(httpRequest.url.includes(`${this.authenticationService.host}/user/register`)) 
    {
        return httpHandler.handle(httpRequest); 
    }
    if(httpRequest.url.includes(`${this.authenticationService.host}/user/resetpassword`)) 
    {
        return httpHandler.handle(httpRequest); 
    }
    this.authenticationService.loadToken(); 
    const token = this.authenticationService.getToken(); 
    
    const request = httpRequest.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}});
    return httpHandler.handle(request);
```

IntelliJ console log:

```
com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException: The token was expected to have 3 parts, but got 4.
    at com.auth0.jwt.TokenUtils.splitToken(TokenUtils.java:21) ~[java-jwt-3.10.0.jar:3.10.0]
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTDecoder.<init>(JWTDecoder.java:34) ~[java-jwt-3.10.0.jar:3.10.0]
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.verify(JWTVerifier.java:246) ~[java-jwt-3.10.0.jar:3.10.0]
    at com.Bug_Tracker.utility.JWTTokenProvider.getSubject(JWTTokenProvider.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.Bug_Tracker.filter.JWTAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAuthorizationFilter.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

jwtfilter:

```
@Component
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private JWTTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(JWTTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(SecurityConstant.OPTIONS_HTTP_METHOD)) // need to check if header structure is valid
        {
            response.setStatus(OK.value()); // if header is good then set it to 200 otherwise we need to get header
        } else
        {//  call getHeader with HttpServletReq which gives me Bearer "token"
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION); // authheader = "Bearer token"
            if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(SecurityConstant.TOKEN_PREFIX))
            {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response); 
                return;
            }   
            String token = authorizationHeader.substring(SecurityConstant.TOKEN_PREFIX.length()); 
            String username = jwtTokenProvider.getSubject(token); 
            if (jwtTokenProvider.isTokenValid(username, token) && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null)
            {                                                        

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthorities(token); // get all authorities from that user
                
                Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(username, authorities, request);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            } else {
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response); 
    }
}
```

when i debug it and click login in angular app authorizationHeader is null:

```
String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
```

in my main file i have a cors-filter as well:

```
@Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Accept", "Jwt-Token", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Jwt-Token", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did, you try and debug in Login.component.ts file if you were able to receive the Token when you called it as 'Jwt-Token' .[ As you have set it to 'Bearer Token'.]

const token = response.headers.get('Jwt-Token');
After this line, try a console.log, or debug to check if you are receiving the token from the backend to the frontend.
Let me know once you try it.

Comment: yes i receive the token, and its gives info in jwt.io as the correct one

Comment: Can you say me whats the addition you have done to the token, that's the mos important thing here.